# Difference between Basic Advanced and preferred for Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm building a google maps API to get all the places from a certain US state, and I don't undestand how the google API pricing work. I've read the [pricing documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#preferred-nearbysearch) but, after reading the API documentatin I'm confused. How do I choose the type of request result I want (Basic v Advanced v Preferred), in the API as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says in the [pricing documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#preferred-nearbysearch) you linked:

> Note: If you select any fields from the Nearby Search (Advanced) SKU, then you are billed at that rate. If you select any fields from the Nearby Search (Preferred) SKU, then you are billed at that rate.

If you include any of the fields from a higher level, your call is billed at that level. So there is no explicit choice of level, you have to check which level the required fields belong to.